# How to debug "Invalid property 'message' of bean class" in a Spring/Java program?

Tags: java, spring

This one is Spring example. I am new to this framework so I don't know how to fix this error.

**MyBean.java** (`MyBean` class in `src` folder)

```
package java4s;

public class MyBean {

    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    public void show() {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

and, this one is my logic java class:

**ClientLogic.java**

```
package java4s;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

public class ClientLogic {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathResource rec=new ClassPathResource("spconfig.xml");
        BeanFactory bf= new XmlBeanFactory(rec);

        Object o=bf.getBean("id1");
        MyBean mb=(MyBean)o;
        mb.show();
    }
}
```

and also I have created one XML file in Java project (spring):

**spconfig.xml**

```
<beans>
    <bean id="id1" class="java4s.ClientLogic">
        <property name="message" value="ganapathi"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**Output:**

```
Aug 30, 2018 2:54:54 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spconfig.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'id1' defined in class path resource [spconfig.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'message' of bean class [java4s.ClientLogic]: No property 'message' found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:169)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:248)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:170)
    at java4s.ClientLogic.main(ClientLogic.java:14)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'message' of bean class [java4s.ClientLogic]: No property 'message' found
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:386)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should visit official spring documentation and read the parts regarding Inversion of Control (aka Dependency Injection).

Your configuration is not what you are trying to do:

```
<bean id="id1" class="java4s.ClientLogic">
```

This defines your class ClientLogic accessible in BeanFactory for Dependency Injection (DI).
I assume you want that to be "MyBean" so it should look like this:

```
<bean id="id1" class="java4s.MyBean ">
```

Note that "id1" is not a good identifier. You should change that too.

Answer (score 0):

you should put MyBean not ClientLogic so it will be  `<bean id="id1" class="java4s.MyBean ">`